# How can I get the /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED directory back if I deleted it

Tags: python, linux, manjaro

I have taken this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip  ✔  26s 
```

error: externally-managed-environment

```
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
    python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
    installed via pacman.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

(I mistook EXTERNALLY-MANAGED for a bug )
i am ran rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
OS Manjaro btrfs

Nothing i dont know what to do
neofetch:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndYso.png)
Python 3.11.3

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just reinstalling python3 with the commands:

```
    sudo pacman -Syu
    sudo pacman -R python-pip
    sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

if you dont mind reinstalling your pip packages and the first thing doesn't work, you can go nuclear:

```
    sudo pacman -Syu
    sudo pacman -Rscn python-pip
    sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

Hope this helps!